# How does using the javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar works at runtime as it is only the API

Tags: rest

We were working on creating a RESTful service. We have thought of using frameworks like jersey or cxf. But apparently we found that just using the javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar and the related annotations, we can get the service working.

Question is:

1. How does it work? Is it dependent on the application servers?
2. What if we application server does not support or have the implementation of the API?
3. If it is dependent on application servers, can I find out the library which the server is using especially tomcat?

**EDIT 1**
This question is invalid. javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar is just an API. Using this jar does not suffice. It will not give compilation errors. 
But at run-time, you need providers which will implement the rs-api. And thus we need the frameworks like jersey or cxf.
In our application, these jars were added to the war during ant-build from external location and that is why it confused us.
I am closing this question.